# Garbled HTML pulled for page description "caption id=attachment..."

Tags: images, html

Whenever someone links to my wordpress blog, whether it's on Facebook, ScoopIt, or whatever, instead of a description, it automatically pulls information from the image:
[image: Example of this happening on ScoopIt]

How do I get this to stop happening? I'd prefer the meta description or something, not some garbled HTML.

Comment: This is not actually a WordPress based problem. Each service provider may get the information from a different location so I can't speak for Scoopit but for the likes of Facebook here is a question which should help you understand this concept better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400947/want-custom-title-image-description-in-facebook-share-link-from-a-flash-app and http://www.bloggersentral.com/2010/11/facebook-share-shows-wrong-description.html and http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

Answer (score 0):

That's shortcode with the brackets stripped. And since shortcode is either rendered or removed before output, it suggests that these descriptions are not merely being "scraped" from your site, but provided by a WordPress plugin or locally-hosted script.

I would first check your theme is not "leaking" raw shortcode; do you see something like `[caption...]` in articles or excerpts when browsing your site?

And if not, are you using any plugins that might be communicating with an aggregator-type service, not necessarily the ones you mentioned? For example, SEO-related plugins.